# What is the correct effective mass formula for an electron near a Brillouin zone edge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrons, mass

In Kittle's Intro to Solid State physics Pg 197, it is stated that the effective mass of an electron near the lower edge of the conduction band is
$$\epsilon (K)= \epsilon_c +\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_{eff}}K^2$$
where
$$\frac{m_{eff}}{m_e}\equiv \frac{1}{2\lambda /U -1} \tag{1} $$
$m_e$ is the mass of a free electron,$\lambda$ is the free electron energy and $K$ is the k-vector measured from the edge.

I am reasonably convinced that Kittle has made a sign error although I am not convinced enough to continue on as if he has.

In the same text on page 179, we calculate the energy near a Brillouin zone edge which leads to the equation
$$\epsilon_K(\pm)=\lambda \pm U +\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}K^2\left(1\pm\frac{2\lambda}{U}\right)$$
This equation seems to indicate that the effective mass ought to be
$$m_{eff}=\frac{m_e}{1\pm \frac{2\lambda}{U}} \tag{2}$$
Note how the denominator in the above equation is different to that in equation (1). My view  is that eq (2) is correct and that (1) is erroneous. Am I correct? I have found alternate sources that seem to agree with eq (2) being correct (for example in the middle of pg 5 here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/3-024-electronic-optical-and-magnetic-properties-of-materials-spring-2013/baecbd9de7692a35421c23aeb626e9e5_MIT3_024S13_2012lec13.pdf).

So has Kittle made an error or is there something I am missing? What is the correct equation for the effective mass of an electron near the Brillouin zone edge?

Comment: I had a look at the book but it's clear that the book is discussing negative masses and it goes into a discussion about that. Perhaps read the preceding and following pages of the book? Sorry if that doesn't help your problem but just a suggestion.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thanks for the response. He is discussing both positive and negative masses. He discusses electrons near the bottom of a conduction band (positive mass) and states that their mass is eq (1). He then discusses electrons at the top of a valence (negative mass) and gives an equation for their effective masses as well. My view is that both equations he provides are wrong. I believe he has made a sign error. The provided link seems to agree but I trust Kittle in general so I am not sure who is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct. Equation (52) on page 179, which is the equation above your equation (2) is right. If I follow Kittel's analysis, I get
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{E}_c + \frac{\hbar^2\tilde{K}^2}{2m}\left(1 + \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right).
\end{equation}
$\mathcal{E}_c$ is indeed the minimum energy of the conduction band and the electron effective mass is
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{1}{m_e^\ast} = \frac{1}{m}\left(1 + \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right) \Rightarrow 
\frac{m_e^\ast}{m} = \left(1 + \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right)^{-1}.
\end{equation}
The second equation gives,
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{E}_v + \frac{\hbar^2\tilde{K}^2}{2m}\left(1 - \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right).
\end{equation}
Kittel mentions that $U$ is positive. Nearly free electron model requires $\lambda \gg U$ so that the bracket is negative. Therefore, $\mathcal{E}_v$ is indeed the maximum of the valence band.

The effective mass of the electron is once again
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial\mathcal{E}}{\partial k^2} = \frac{1}{\hbar^2}\frac{\partial\mathcal{E}}{\partial \tilde{K}^2}
\end{equation}
as $\tilde{K} = k - G/2$. In this case it is negative. Therefore, we define the hole effective mass and the negative of that quantity, which is
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\frac{1}{m_h^\ast} = -\frac{1}{m_e^\ast} = -\frac{1}{m}\left(1 - \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right) \Rightarrow \frac{m_h^\ast}{m} = -\left(1 - \frac{2\lambda}{U}\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{2\lambda}{U} - 1\right)^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Equations (2) and (5) correspond to his equations (24) and (25) except that the definitions of effective mass in are swapped.

With this choice everything seems to be tying together well. I hope that I haven't made a mistake. Let me know if I have.